# For self-adjoint automorphism $T$, to what extent is $U \circ T \circ S$ equivalent to $U \circ S$?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism, self-adjoint-operators

I would like to know to what extent can composition with self-adjoint isomorphism affect composition of linear operators. More specifically, for linear operators of Hilbert spaces as $H \xrightarrow{S} H' \xrightarrow{T} H' \xrightarrow{U} H''$ so that $T$ is self-adjoint vector-space-automorphism, is there an equivalence between $U \circ S$ and $U \circ T \circ S$ so that would exist vector-space-automorphisms $I \colon H,J \colon H''$ so that $J \circ (U \circ S) \circ I = U \circ T \circ S$. Does this apply if the spaces are finite-dimensional?

Comment: If $S$ is invertible then $$UTS=US(S^{-1}TS)$$ Similarly if $U$ is invertible then $$UTS=(UTU^{-1}) US$$

Comment: If you are really talking of "vector-space-automorphims" (and not *inner product* vector space automorphisms), in finite dimension this would be equivalent to : $U\circ S$ and $U\circ T\circ S$ have the same rank. Which is generally false. Look for a counterexample in dimension $2.$

Comment: E.g. $S(e_1)=e_1,S(e_2)=0,U=S,T(e_1)=e_2,T(e_2)=e_1.$

Comment: I got it, thanks Anne!